# Swift initialize a struct with a closure

Tags: swift, closures, init

```
public struct Style {

    public var test : Int?

    public init(_ build:(Style) -> Void) {
       build(self)
    }
}

var s = Style { value in
    value.test = 1
}
```

gives an error at the declaration of the variable

```
Cannot find an initializer for type 'Style' that accepts an argument list of type '((_) -> _)'
```

Does anyone know why this won't work, it seems legit code to me

for the record this won't work either

```
var s = Style({ value in
    value.test = 1
})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The closure passed to the constructor *modifies* the given argument,
therefore it must take an *inout-parameter* and be called with `&self`:

```
public struct Style {

    public var test : Int?

    public init(_ build:(inout Style) -> Void) {
        build(&self)
    }
}

var s = Style { (inout value : Style) in
    value.test = 1
}

println(s.test) // Optional(1)
```

Note that using `self` (as in `build(&self)`) requires that all its
properties have been initialized. This works here because optionals
are implicitly initialized to `nil`. Alternatively you could define
the property as a non-optional with an initial value:

```
public var test : Int = 0
```